# Can VS Code remote development be used with "Azure App Services" or "Containers on Azure App services"?

Tags: azure, docker, visual-studio-code, azure-web-app-service, vscode-remote

B"H

I've been using VS Codes Remote-Containers extension recently to develop directly in containers on my dev machine. It's been a real productivity boost.

There is a second extension (part of the same pack) call Remote-SSH for connecting to VMs running in the cloud. You can then run VS code on your local dev machine but be editing files and running commands in the terminal directly on the remote machine.

I've seen tutorials on how to use that on full blown linux VMs. However I haven't seen any examples of connecting it to either Web Apps / Azure App Services or Containers running in the cloud.

---

Can either of these extensions (or some combination of them) be used to connect to a container running in Azure (on an App Service) or to an App service?